# While accessing SSH/SHELL The security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running in mozilla/ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, ssh, java

While logging in the Cpanel ssh shell from Mozilla firefox in ubuntu It says : The application cannot be run Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running.? (Instead of terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should install the certificate of your server locally first? if you are using a self signed you have to configure SSH to accept it

Visit https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu

this was suposed to be a comment but i dont have enough rep for it.